# Handlebars VueJS escape img src

Tags: vue.js, handlebars.js

To use VueJS data variables in my hbs view engine I need to add this `\` before the variable so it looks like this for example `\{{name}}` - this would show the name from vue data variable `name`.

Now I cannot find a way to do this with img src.

```
    <div v-for="item in itemsImgArr">
        <img src="{{item.img}}">
        \{{item.img}} - returns me a normal img link
    </div>
```

I have tried this option: `<img src="\" + "{{ item.img }}">`  but it doesn't work. I've tried to experiment but I cannot get the link. Maybe someone could help ?

Answer (score 1):

So if anybody uses Handlebars with VueJS you can show images like this:

`<img :src="item.img">` and it works perfectly!